# Transformational geometry problem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

There are two circles and a line $g$. The line doesn't intersect any of the two circles. How to construct a square and what kind of transformation to use such that the two vertices are in the line $g$ and the other two vertices are in the circles: one vertex is in one circle and the other vertex is in the other circle.

The problem stems from my transformational geometry textbook and I have no idea how to solve unless, I construct the square using a ruler and compass without using transformation

Comment: If the circles are on opposite sides of the line, or if they are sufficiently far apart compared to their radii, no square with the stated properties exists. Could you please clarify the hypotheses of your question (and perhaps the conclusion, as well)? If this comes from a book, it's certainly worth giving a complete citation, but it may also be a good idea to add the text of the question to your post. Thank you. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, sorry it is originally stated in Bahasa Indonesia. The translation version is exactly the same as the original problem. There is no condition stated for the circles and the line. Anyway, I have a question, how come you conclude that it will make no square if the circles are on opposite sides of the line. I think it is still possible

Comment: My apology: I misread "two vertices are in the line" as "one side of the square lies along the line" (i.e. two _neighboring_ vertices are in the line).

Comment: I still don't see that it is always possible. If the circles are on opposite sides of the line and the difference in distances to the line is greater than the diameters, no such square can exist. Or is the idea that you first apply some transformation to make it possible?